# Autoit OnAutoItExitRegister() does not seem to work

Tags: exit, autoit, shutdown

Some programs seem to change my InitialKeyboardIndicators registry value so I added a OnAutoItExitRegister to my autoit daemon that reverts the changes in the registry.
It does not seem to work however. It just does not do anything. I tried it out with a messagebox that contains the exitmethod and its working flawless, even the registry values are changed but it prevents windows from shutting down. Here are the essential parts:

```
OnAutoItExitRegister("Registry")

While 1
sleep(2147483647)
WEnd

Func Registry()
RegWrite("HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-4085687063-2130025463-4060534026-1001\Control Panel\Keyboard", "InitialKeyboardIndicators", "REG_SZ", 2147483650)
FileWrite(@DesktopDir & "test.txt", @exitMethod)
EndFunc
```

I added the FileWrite for debbuging purposes but it does not create a file either.

Comment: Ehm, how do you want to find this out? You just sleep for Ages... You didn't try to wait this long to see a result? And there is no call of the Exit function either... When you Exit a Script via the Tray Menu, it might not be executed because the Script will be killed... considered this as an explanation? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The function works pretty well.
You need to add \ to your FileWrite

```
FileWrite(@DesktopDir & "\test.txt", @exitMethod)
```